# Linting is extremely slow after upgrading nx/angular . Plugin: import/no-deprecated

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, nomachine-nx

The project has been upgraded from `11.2.11` to `12.2.10` during the nx upgrade process (`nx migrate`)

Now, the code linting increased from 30 seconds to 4 minutes:

```
 time TIMING=1 ng lint my-app

> nx run my-app:lint 

Linting "my-app"...

All files pass linting.

Rule                                       |  Time (ms) | Relative
:------------------------------------------|-----------:|--------:
import/no-deprecated                       | 204887.182 |    99.6%
@nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries         |    260.016 |     0.1%
@typescript-eslint/naming-convention       |     83.345 |     0.0%
max-len                                    |     66.311 |     0.0%
comma-dangle                               |     40.576 |     0.0%
no-global-assign                           |     23.094 |     0.0%
@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars          |     22.934 |     0.0%
@typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing |     22.831 |     0.0%
no-misleading-character-class              |     18.360 |     0.0%
@typescript-eslint/triple-slash-reference  |     16.281 |     0.0%

———————————————————————————————————————————————

>  NX   SUCCESS  Running target "lint" succeeded



real    3m41.726s
user    4m19.102s
sys     0m23.049s
```

```
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "12.2.10",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "12.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "12.2.10",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.2.10",
    ...
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "12.10.0",
    ...
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
```

eslint settings: `"import/no-deprecated": "warn",`

Were there any settings changed or I should get rid of this import?

Answer (score 0):

Check your app tsConfig, In my case, the "include" property was missing so the lint time was too high.

```
    {
       "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"],
       "files": ["./src/main.ts", "./src/polyfills.ts"],
       "exclude": ["./src/test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts"]
   }
```